# Getting null fields in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have a customer name with first name, last name, middle name. I want to concatenate these fields. When I concatenate these fields I am getting some of the fields as null cause as it contains at least one null value field. I have tried with this formula.

```
{FIRST_NAME}&","&{MIDDLE_NAME}&","&{LAST_NAME}
```

Ex: I have first name, last name but middle name is null then I am getting entire field as null.
Please help me how to resolve this.

Comment: looks like you're looking for something like this http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/17675-crystal-reports-using-blank-or-null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably want to wrap each field with a formula to adjust for `null`s:

```
// {@FIRST_NAME}
If Isnull({table.FIRST_NAME}) Then "" Else {table.FIRST_NAME}
```

Then create a formula to concatenate them

```
// {@FULL_NAME}
{@FIRST_NAME} + "," + {@MIDDLE_NAME} + "," + {@LAST_NAME}
```