# Crystal Reports combine fields in string formula, one field no data

Tags: string, crystal-reports, formula

I was given a formula:

```
if not (isnull({PERSON.LAST_NAME})) then 
{PERSON.LAST_NAME}+","+" "+{PERSON.FIRST_NAME}
else 
"No Name"
```

This formula seems to work fine but I need to add the field {PERSON.MIDDLE_NAME} however when I write the formula

```
if not (isnull({PERSON.LAST_NAME})) then 
{PERSON.LAST_NAME}+","+" "+{PERSON.FIRST_NAME}+","+" "+{PERSON.MIDDLE_NAME}
else 
"No Name"
```

if the person has a middle name, it looks fine. If the person does not have a middle name and there is no data in the field, then the report shows no information at all.

Apologies for what is likely a very beginner question, and thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like you are doing null string concatenation. There are some pointers on this site http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=2422

Comment: See my answer to this question: [getting-null-fields-in-crystal-reports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910950/getting-null-fields-in-crystal-reports)

Comment: Thank you @WhiteboardDev the information in your link solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you @craig the information in your link solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can nest an additional if statement to evaluate the middle name. Sometimes I like to break criteria like this into multiple formulas. You could create a separate formula for fname, lname, mname. Each would have an if statement similar to above (if isnull({mname} then "" else {mname}).

Then you can create an additional formula to concatenate them all together {lastname} + {firstname} + {middlename}